When use getRecordTypeInfos throws error "Access to entity 'SalesforceContract' denied" in apex class
I write code to describe all objects and get record types of those objects like the below code:
for (Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult obj = o.getDescribe();    
        system.debug('record type size: '+obj.getRecordTypeInfos().size());
}

This code throws the error like:

Access to entity 'SalesforceContract' denied

Does anyone know the resolution? what was the cause of this error?

From this help.salesforce.com article, I can theorize that this object is not accessible and shouldn't have come up as a result of Schema.getGlobalDescribe().
Especially from the 2nd point saying "Ideally Salesforce Contract object shouldn’t be visible in the object manager. Salesforce has explicitly disabled it.":
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000570798&type=1
So I guess the only workaround for now is to add it to some kind of an exception list to not try and describe it.

not accessible in a scratch org per the Help article; should be accessible in a PROD org; and rather than maintaining an exception list, just catch the exception and ignore it

You can also check isAccessible() as well before making method calls on it.
